# Are there graphs with non integer number of nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

Graphs have a number of nodes $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I wonder if the number of nodes can be rational or real ($n \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $n \in \mathbb{R}$).

What would be a natural way to extend the concept of graph to a non integer number of nodes? How would the graph look?

Comment: "Fraction graph theory" could mean [whatever you define it to mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty#Lewis_Carroll's_Through_the_Looking-Glass).  For example suppose you had a conventional graph, and then selected subgraphs from it by some random process.  You might be able to assign a probability of being selected to each node and edge, and thereby find the expected number of nodes and edges in a selection; you might also be able to determine useful relationships. Perhaps this "expected subgraph" might then be said to have a number of nodes which was not necessarily an integer.

Comment: You might find https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/counting/ interesting. It starts, "We all know what it means for a set to have 6 elements, but what sort of thing has -1 elements, or 5/2? Believe it or not, these questions have nice answers." If a set can have 5/2 elements, maybe a graph can have 5/2 nodes.

Comment: Had a look at that link?

Comment: @Gerry MyersonIt is a ton to digest, and most of it goes over my head, but I'm looking at it

Comment: Good. I agree, it's written at a high level, but as far as I know it's the only attempt to deal with sets with a fractional (or negative) number of elements.